# Regexp Numeric with Single Decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've written the following js with regexp. It works as expected, however I'm looking to simplify it. Could somebody help me out?

**.12345** - success

**0.12345** - success

**12345.12345** - success

**0.123456** fail - this I wish was dynamic and not restricted to 5

**1.123.45** fail

**1..** fail

**..** fail

**abc** - fail

```
function clearNonNumericChars(field) {        
    field.val(field.val().replace(/([^0-9\.])/g,""));
    field.val(field.val().replace(/^(\d*\.[0-9]{5})\d+$/g,"$1"));
    field.val(field.val().replace(/(\.\d*)(\.)$/g,"$1"));
}
```

Comment: Is the `.` mandatory?  ie, do you wish `725` to pass or fail?  What about `725.` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does success/fail mean?

Comment: It's not clear what's your goal. You want have a validation function, where it will returns false if the argument given it's not a valid number? Or you want "clean" any string given in order to have a valid number? In the last scenario what are the constraints?

Comment: I need to remove any non numeric characters but optionally allow only 1 decimal. I'm performing this test on keyup.

Comment: You say that `0.123456` currently fails, but do you want it to pass or fail? Sounds like you _don't_ want that 5-digit limit after the decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

Don't deal with numbers as strings.

```
isNumberValid = function(n) {
    return (n == Math.round(n*10000)/10000)
}
```

Comment: This just tells me whether it's numeric or not, it doesn't allow me to remove a non numeric character on keyup.

Comment: @George: You never said anything about doing anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex if you don't want one, if you are doing this on keyup. Just filter by keycode/which in your event handler. You've marked the question jQuery, so:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.which, [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,190]) === -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Note I haven't really tested this, but this basically makes it so the user can't enter anything but numbers or the decimal. Note that they can still paste bad characters in. I'll leave the solution for that to the reader...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? >>

```
var str = "1a2..b3.C4;56";
str = str.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"").replace(/\./,",").replace(/\./g,"").replace(/,/,"."); 
print(str);
```

Live test at http://ideone.com/F7wWV

Comment: And optionally you can append `.replace(/^0+/,"")` or `.replace(/^0+/,"0")` to handle leading zero(s).